# Why does A in Max Black's "Identity of Indiscernibles" assert that there is nothing verifiably different between the twin world and no-twin world?

Tags: identity, universals

i just finished "Identity of Indiscernibles" by Max Black  and I'm a bit confused.

In Max Black's paper, A (the character that asserts that the identity of indiscernibles is true) says to B (the denier) that a world that has things that is radially symmetrical to itself is not verifiably different from a world that does not(this is the part after the famous two-ball example, p.162). Why does A do so? Can't A say there is a difference for the world where there is a pair of things differ from the world with just one of each thing in their relational properties to the copies of themselves? Why does A bite the bullet and claim the two universes are indistinguishable?

thanks to any answers!

Comment: Relevant to B's statement (page 162) regarding modern physics and electrons, see Steven French & Décio Krause, [Identity in Physics: A Historical Philosophical and Formal Analysis (Oxford University Press, 2006)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Identity_in_Physics/q_ATDAAAQBAJ)